# Creating a grep loop to find character values and then map matches in new Column

Tags: r, loops

I have a data frame with one columns. I am trying to create a mapping file and want the grep command to show which match was pulled.

```
df<- data.frame("Restaurant" = c("Dominos Pizza", "Papa Johns Pizza", "Dairy Queen Ice Cream", "Dennys Breakfast")
```

I have tried:

```
tags<- c("Pizza", "Breakfast", "Cream")

for (i in length(tags)) {
df$i <- df[grep(i, df$Restaurant),]
  
}
```

I want my desired output to be:

Restaurant
Dominos Pizza
Pappa Johns Pizza
Dairy Queen Ice Cream

[image]

I then can melt the df to create the mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You can use `ifelse()` and `grepl()` to test the conditions and then use the same `tags` values to create the new variables. Here the code:

```
#Data
df<- data.frame("Restaurant" = c("Dominos Pizza", "Papa Johns Pizza", "Dairy Queen Ice Cream", "Dennys Breakfast"),stringsAsFactors = F)
tags<- c("Pizza", "Breakfast", "Cream")
#Loop
for(i in 1:length(tags))
{
  df[[tags[i]]] <- ifelse(grepl(tags[i],df$Restaurant),df$Restaurant,NA)
}
```

Output:

```
df
             Restaurant            Pizza        Breakfast                 Cream
1         Dominos Pizza    Dominos Pizza             <NA>                  <NA>
2      Papa Johns Pizza Papa Johns Pizza             <NA>                  <NA>
3 Dairy Queen Ice Cream             <NA>             <NA> Dairy Queen Ice Cream
4      Dennys Breakfast             <NA> Dennys Breakfast                  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thought, no loop required:

```r
# add the closing paren
df<- data.frame("Restaurant" = c("Dominos Pizza", "Papa Johns Pizza", "Dairy Queen Ice Cream", "Dennys Breakfast"))
tags<- c("Pizza", "Breakfast", "Cream")

df <- cbind(df, sapply(tags, grepl, df$Restaurant))
df
#              Restaurant Pizza Breakfast Cream
# 1         Dominos Pizza  TRUE     FALSE FALSE
# 2      Papa Johns Pizza  TRUE     FALSE FALSE
# 3 Dairy Queen Ice Cream FALSE     FALSE  TRUE
# 4      Dennys Breakfast FALSE      TRUE FALSE
```

From here, it's not too hard to replace the logicals with actual strings:

```r
df[,-1] <- lapply(df[,-1], function(lgl) replace(df$Restaurant, !lgl, values = NA_character_))
df
#              Restaurant            Pizza        Breakfast                 Cream
# 1         Dominos Pizza    Dominos Pizza             <NA>                  <NA>
# 2      Papa Johns Pizza Papa Johns Pizza             <NA>                  <NA>
# 3 Dairy Queen Ice Cream             <NA>             <NA> Dairy Queen Ice Cream
# 4      Dennys Breakfast             <NA> Dennys Breakfast                  <NA>
```

---

Alternatives that do much the same thing. Starting with the 1-column `df`:

```r
cbind(df, lapply(setNames(nm = tags), function(tg) replace(df$Restaurant, !grepl(tg, df$Restaurant), NA_character_)))
#              Restaurant            Pizza        Breakfast                 Cream
# 1         Dominos Pizza    Dominos Pizza             <NA>                  <NA>
# 2      Papa Johns Pizza Papa Johns Pizza             <NA>                  <NA>
# 3 Dairy Queen Ice Cream             <NA>             <NA> Dairy Queen Ice Cream
# 4      Dennys Breakfast             <NA> Dennys Breakfast                  <NA>
```

or

```r
cbind(df, lapply(setNames(nm = tags), function(tg) ifelse(grepl(tg, df$Restaurant), df$Restaurant, NA_character_)))
#              Restaurant            Pizza        Breakfast                 Cream
# 1         Dominos Pizza    Dominos Pizza             <NA>                  <NA>
# 2      Papa Johns Pizza Papa Johns Pizza             <NA>                  <NA>
# 3 Dairy Queen Ice Cream             <NA>             <NA> Dairy Queen Ice Cream
# 4      Dennys Breakfast             <NA> Dennys Breakfast                  <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the first set of code works great but the second one is returning this error meassage  Error in !lgl : invalid argument type

Comment: Not sure what to say ... it works for me when the columns are of class `logical`. Does `str(df)` suggest that `Pizza` (etc) are all logicals? You should see `Pizza     : logi ...`.

Comment: Yes it does, the code runs without the ! before lgl but not the correct output obviously

Comment: okay, are there other columns you haven't shared? `df[,-1]` means every column except the first one (`$Restaurant`), perhaps you're using too many columns? Try `df[,2:4] <- lapply(df[,2:4], ...)`

Comment: I can reproduce that error only when the logical columns are no longer logical. For instance, if you run my code above (with my data ... work with me here) from `df <- data.frame(...)` through `df[,-1] <- lapply(...)`, then rerun that last `lapply` command, I see the error. If you accidentally ran it twice, that error is correct, don't do that. If you are using too many columns, then be more specific (in your code) which columns, not just `-1`. Whatever change you do to the column indices on the LHS, do it on the RHS too.

Comment: Yeah I have one more identifier column on the LHS

Comment: So does removing that column from both sides resolve the problem?